# How do you write a declaration in racket that returns either a string or #f (false)?

Tags: types, racket, declaration

I have the following function in racket:

( : search-stack : Symbol KeyStack -> String)
(define (search-stack s stack)

This function searches the stack for a specific string and returns the matching symbol. If the string is not found, the function returns "#f". How do I modify the return type to allow for returning either a string or boolean type (false only)?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the simpler function match, which just checks a pair (which could be
one element of a stack). With *signature* (informal type as a comment) this could be:

```
#lang racket

(define (match s p) ;; Symbol (Symbol . String) -> "String or #f"
  ;; produce string if s matches, otherwise #f
  (if (eq? s (car p))
      (cdr p)
      #f))
```

In typed-racket, with type annotations on the arguments, this is:

```
#lang typed/racket

(define (match [s : Symbol] [p : (Pairof Symbol String)])
  (if (eq? s (car p))
      (cdr p)
      #f))
```

Now just type `match` into the DrRacket interactions area, and type induction
will reveal the return type:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 8.4 [cs].
Language: typed/racket, with debugging.
> match
- : (-> Symbol (Pairof Symbol String) (U False String))
#<procedure:match>
>
```